# Place a label before input

Tags: jquery

I cannot seem to get a label to show up next to my input when I use `.before()` or `.after()`

```
this.vehicle = $('<input>');

this.vehicle.attr({
    id: "invoiceItemVehicle",
    name: "invoiceItemVehicle",
    class: "invoiceItemControl"
});
this.vehicle.before('<label>Vehicle</label>');
this.vehicle.after('<br /><br />');
```

For some reason,

```
this.vehicle.append('<label>Vehicle</label>');
```

will put the label inside the input, but nothing happens when I use `.before()` and `.after()`. I am not getting any error messages either. Is this a problem with jquery input handling?

The desired output is Vehicle: ***_*__*_*__*_*_** (double line break)

Comment: `append` adds it to your `this.vehicle` which is an `input` field.. so that is no strange thing. Try appending your input to the document first and then do the `before` and / or `after`.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery wrap() function.

HTML for test:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

And JS:

```
this.vehicle = $('<input>');

this.vehicle.attr({
    id: "invoiceItemVehicle",
    name: "invoiceItemVehicle",
    class: "invoiceItemControl"
});
this.vehicle.wrap('<label>Vehicle: </label>');
$('.test').append(this.vehicle.parent());
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/yuemvbp5